# Getting clear idea about casting and inheritance in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I can't get a clear idea about inheritance in Java. For instance, I have:

```
class A
{ 
     ...
     public void MethodA();
}
```

Here is everything is clear. Then I want a (sub)class:

```
class B extends A
{
    ...
    public void MethodB();
}
```

Then I create an instance of `A`. Then I want to get an instance of `B` having all the stuff from `A`. I want to make something like `aA = new B();` but get an error.

Using this thing is not really comfortable:

`A aA = new A(...);

 B aB = new B(null,null,...);

 aB = aA`

How should I make it correctly and get a clear idea about inheritance in Java?

UPD: So how can i get an instance of B having all the stuff of A?

Comment: Every dog is an animal, but not every animal is a dog.

Comment: "_So how can i get an instance of B having all the stuff of A?_" Do nothing. Every instance of `B` already _has all of the stuff_ of `A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want an instance of `B` in the first place. Once you have such an instance, you can use it whenever *either* `A` *or* `B` is required.

Put another way, every instance of `B` is automatically also an instance of `A`.

This is called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, A - superclass, B - subclass.

A subclass possesses all the attributes and operations of its superclass (because a subclass inherited all attributes and operations from its superclass). This means that a subclass object can do whatever its superclass can do. As a result, we can substitute a subclass instance when a superclass instance is expected, and everything shall work fine. This is called substitutability.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the *IS-A* relationship. Let's discuss an example of *Employee and Manager* relationship.

```
class Employee{
    public Employee(){
        System.out.println("Employee obj");
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee{
    public Manager(){
        System.out.println("Manager obj");
    }
}
```

By extending *Employee* we are declaring *Manager* as a specialization of *Employee*. Therefore, every *Manager* is an *Employee* but every *Employee* is not *Manager*.

A reference of type *Employee* can refer to the objects who satisfy the *IS-A* relationship. Therefore, these are perfectly legal to write:

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
Employee emp2 = new Manager();
```

However, if we try to write

```
Manager man1 = new Employee(); //Wrong: Compilation error.
```

This violates the *IS-A* relationship. As a result of this we get compile time error. In order to avoid this kind of compilation error we need to add a cast to type *Manager*. But, casting to type *Manager* only avoids compilation issues. You will get a *java.lang.ClassCastException* as a result of of this kind of casting.

```
Manager man1 = (Manager) new Employee(); //Wrong: avoids compilation error but will generate a ClassCastException at runtime.
```

I suggest you to go through the [Java Language Specification: Section 5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1) to get a full idea of casting a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

*Every* instance of `B` has all of stuff from `A`, because it *is* an `A`. But it seems like you actually want to create an instance of `B` from a *given* instance of `A`. This isn't possible, unless you specifically write your class so as to allow it:

```
public class B extends A {
  public B(A original) { ... }
}
```

and later

```
 A a = new A();
 B b = new B(a);
```